# Winston logger with MongoDB, if there is an error it saves on both collections (errorLog and infoLog), It should only save on "errorLog" collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, logging, winston

This is my code. If the level: "info" it's insert only one on (infoLog) collection, but if the level: "error" it's insert on both collection (errorLog & infoLog) collection. How I can fix this issue?

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require("winston");
const { combine, timestamp, prettyPrint } = format;
require("dotenv").config();
require("winston-mongodb");
const logger = createLogger({
  format: format.combine(
    format.timestamp({
      format: "DD-MM-YYYY  HH:mm:ss Z ",
    }),
    format.json(),
    format.metadata()
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console(),
    new transports.MongoDB({
      level: "info",
      db: "mongodb://localhost:27017/oos",
      options: {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
      },
      collection: "infoLog",
    }),
    new transports.MongoDB({
      level: "error",
      db: "mongodb://localhost:27017/oos",
      options: {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
      },
      collection: "errorLog",
    }),
  ],
});

module.exports = logger;
```

This is what showing on console log
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mL1T.png)

```
{"level":"error","message":"(test@yahoo.com) Invalid Credential & User Not Found!!! ","timestamp":"30-09-2022  11:30:01 +08:00 "}
```

There are the collection data saved
[errorLog Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqHO1.png)
[infoLog Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg7aw.png)

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("633662b98435813e681353e7"),
"timestamp" : ISODate("2022-09-30T11:30:01.056+08:00"),
"level" : "error",
"message" : "(test@yahoo.com) Invalid Credential & User Not Found!!! ",
"meta" : {
    "timestamp" : "30-09-2022  11:30:01 +08:00 "
}
```

}

This is the logger:

```
 logger.error(`(${email}) Invalid Credential & User Not Found!!! `);
```

Comment: What is the problem to store all logs in one collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution at https://betterstack.com/community/guides/logging/how-to-install-setup-and-use-winston-and-morgan-to-log-node-js-applications/#configuring-transports-in-winston

Could be this one:

```
const errorFilter = winston.format((info, opts) => {
  return info.level === 'error' ? info : false;
});

const infoFilter = winston.format((info, opts) => {
  return info.level === 'info' ? info : false;
});

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  transports: [
    new transports.MongoDB({
      level: "error",
      db: "mongodb://localhost:27017/oos",
      options: { useUnifiedTopology: true },
      collection: "errorLog",
      format: combine(errorFilter(), ...),
    }),
    new transports.MongoDB({
      level: "info",
      db: "mongodb://localhost:27017/oos",
      options: { useUnifiedTopology: true },
      collection: "infoLog",
      format: combine(infoFilter(), ...),
    }),
  ],
});
```

Maybe you can try also this:

```
const collectionName = winston.collection((info, opts) => {
  return `${info.level}Log`;
});

new transports.MongoDB({
  level: "info",
  db: "mongodb://localhost:27017/oos",
  options: {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  },
  collection: collectionName(),
}),
```

Comment: Thank you @Wernfried Domscheit for your time to answer the question. It's working for me, I appreciate it.

Comment: In this case, please accept the answer.